# Do the way that I name the hash key influence partitioning in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to use a table where several objects can share the same initial characters in the hash primary key (e.g. Timestamp). I am wondering if that influences partitioning. I guess no, since that objects are randomly accessed and AWS documentation gives an example where several objects has the same initial key D17 (the device id example). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, they hash the value that you provide with a private algorithm.  The hash function prevents you from accidentally creating "hotter" key areas, and keeping it private prevents someone from knowingly relying on the current characteristics, as they may change it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, hash key is distributed in different partitions, while range key are always stored in the in the same partition than the owner hash key. 
I guess a timestamp hash key distribution is suitable for avoding hotspots at is explained here:
[Guidelines for Working With Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns)